# Inserting into SQLite database - Android

Tags: java, android, sqlite, nullpointerexception

I am trying to implement a SQLite database for a highscores table.  I am just testing it to see if my database creation and insertion is working with the below code.  But I am getting a NullPointerException on the below lines.

Thank you in advance!

Results.java

```
public class Results extends Activity {
    DatabaseHelper dh;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        dh = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);

    public void showResults() {
        dh.openDB();  
        dh.insert(1231423, 436346);  //Line 104
    }
}
```

DatabaseHelper.java

```
private static final String SCORE = "score"; 
private static final String PERCENTAGE = "percentage";
public static DatabaseHelper mSingleton = null;

public synchronized static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context context) {
    if(mSingleton == null) {
        mSingleton = new DatabaseHelper(context.getApplicationContext());
    }
    return mSingleton;
}

public SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
    return this.getWritableDatabase();
}

public long insert(long score, int percentage) {
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(SCORE, score);  
    values.put(PERCENTAGE, percentage); 

    return db.insert(TABLE, null, values);  //Line 91
}
```

LogCat output

```
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.Results}: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:91)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.example.test.Results.showResults(Results.java:104)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at com.example.test.Results.onCreate(Results.java:50)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
01-02 17:56:47.609: E/AndroidRuntime(1322):     ... 11 more
```

**EDIT:** The NullPointerException is at least jumping around but errors still are there.  I have edited my code and posted the new LogCat output.

Comment: Are you initializing DatabaseHelper dh; somewhere?

Comment: As the exception clearly states, the problem is at `Results.showResults` which I don't see anywhere in your post

Comment: I bet you forgot to call the open() method on your database

Comment: @K-ballo the dh.insert() call is in the showResults() method in the class Results.  Sorry for the confusion.  I should have shown that in my code posted.

Comment: @StefandeBruijn I never initialized DatabaseHelper dh anywhere.  Could that be a problem?

Comment: The `1231423` and `436346` is just an int and long that I randomly chose to test if the `insert()` method was correct.

Comment: You added this line to your LogCat: `at com.example.test.DatabaseHelper.insert(DatabaseHelper.java:91)` which is exactly what my answer addresses. Let me know how it works.

Comment: You're right, I changed my code to match your answer and the NPE went away from the spot previously.  A NPE is still present, only at a different location now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `openDB()` to save the SqliteDatabase it opens and open a *writable* database:

```
public void openDB() {
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
}
```

But this still doesn't match your stack trace, however it matches the code you provided.

Comment: I fixed what you suggested and the NPE went away.  A NPE still exists just at a different spot now.  I updated my opening post if you do not mind taking another look at it.

Comment: You are still using `return this.getWritableDatabase();` change it too `db = this.getWritableDatabase();`.

Comment: Oh whoops, I thought I had it but apparently didn't.  It works now!  I now need to work on pulling back out what I inserted and displaying it to TextViews.  Thanks again Sam.

Answer (score 1):

You said you are doing:

```
DatabaseHelper dh;

dh.insert(1231423, 436346);
```

Looks like you are not instantiating dh:

```
dh = new DatabaseHelper(this);
```

A better approach would be to use the singleton pattern as you are ever going to need just one DatabaseHelper instance:

```
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "table_name";
private static final int SCHEME_VERSION = 1;
public static DatabaseHelper mSingleton = null;

private DatabaseHelper(Context ctxt) {
    super(ctxt, DATABASE_NAME, null, SCHEME_VERSION);
}

public synchronized static DatabaseHelper getInstance(Context ctxt) {
    if (mSingleton == null)
        mSingleton = new DatabaseHelper(ctxt.getApplicationContext());
    return mSingleton;
}
```

Now you can call like so:

```
DatabaseHelper dh = DatabaseHelper.getInstance(this);
```

Comment: The NPE is jumping around after implementing everything you had above.  I edited my opening post and the new code, errors and LogCat.

Answer (score 0):

If you are following the common SqlliteHelper pattern, you are likely to have forgotten to call the .open() method before calling insert.

Comment: You are right, I did not call open().  Should that be added in as the first line of code in the insert() method?

Comment: A way to use it is to call open() in onResume() method and close() in onPause() methods of your activity.

Comment: I updated what @StefandeBruijn and you suggested and edited my opening post with errors commented into the code.  I made the code a little more clearer too.

Comment: I think you should init db in your public SQLiteDatabase openDB() {
    return this.getReadableDatabase();
} , something like db = this.getReadableDatabase()

Answer (score -1):

```
package com.example.hostelmangement;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DataBaseHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory,
        int version)
{
    super(context, name, factory, version);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSQL("create table demo(id integer primary key,join_date date,name text,father_name text,date_of_birth text,house_name text,place text,pin_no text,blood_group text,mobile text,email text,company text,company_place text,company_phone text,company_pin,rent text,pending integer,status text,photo text,Proof text)");

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```

}